# Irregular output from DC Motor used as a generator?

Tags: dc-motor, generator, three-phase, energy-harvesting

I was trying to make a generator out of a DC motor inrunner by following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vnjCrLTMGxQ) by following this schematic:
[image: 1]
[image]

I made this structure and started testing the phase voltages. A-, B+, C- are combined together and made as the neutral wire.
[image]

While testing the voltage outputs from A_neutral, B_neutral, C_neutral, V_ab, V_bc and V_ac, I am getting non-uniform outputs and I am getting problems troubleshooting this issue.

### **Voltage_cb**

[image: Voltage_cb]

### **Voltage_ab**

[image: Voltage_ab]

### **Voltage_ac**

[image: Voltage_ac]

### **Voltage_a_with_neutral**

[image: Voltage_a_with_neutral]

### **Voltage_b_with_neutral**

[image: Voltage_b_with_neutral]

### **Voltage_c_with_neutral (almost no voltage, dont know why)**

[image: Voltage_c_with_neutral (almost no voltage, dont know why)]

Why is the voltage_cneutral almost nil compared to the other voltages? I checked the copper coil winding and they are all same.

Comment: Most of us won't watch a video link. (1) Add a schematic using the button on the editor toolbar. (2) Explain what "inrunner" means. (I never heard of it.) (3) Explain the change in voltage on the a-N trace.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated. Although I am not ale to explain the change in the voltage on the a-N trace, I was moving around the wires for adjustment which caused a big surge. I still have not understood.

Comment: You don't have a neutral, you don't need a neutral. Where did your neutral come from??? Maybe your neutral is the problem?? You only need to rectify the 3 phases with 6 diodes, no neutral in sight. Look up '3 phase full wave recitifier'.

Comment: (1) You still haven't explained "inrunner". (2) There is no neutral on those wiring diagrams.

Comment: @Neil_UK A-, B+ and C- are soldered together and made as neutral

Comment: @Neil_UK A+, B- and C+ are the three phase inputs.

Comment: @Transistor Inrunner is a type of brushless motor that is used in radio controlled models

Comment: "inrunner" implies "BLDC" which implies it generates 3-phase AC.  The OP needs a 3-phase bridge rectifier (6 diodes) to get his DC output. At a wild guess, unless he's wired it Y not Delta, there is no neutral (I'm not going to attempt to read his scribble, he also needs to draw a proper schematic)

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes this is a Y configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a loose connection somewhere. With magnet wire, you need to carefully scrape the varnish off the surface of the wires, twist them together and solder them. The voltage A to neutral trace shows the voltage jumping up and down. That must be the result of a loose connection. The scope patterns seem to be inconsistent with one another. It appears that moving the scope probes may move the wires so that the connections change.

Comment: I found the problem, it was giving inconsistent output because of main line interference similar to [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78920/my-scope-detects-a-50hz-signal-when-the-probe-is-not-connected-to-a-circuit-is).